# Why can't we use JSTL fn tags independently, just like core tags

Tags: jsp, jstl, jstl-functions

If `functions` tag library are also part of JSTL then why can't (or don't) we use them like other tags? For example, with `core` we can say something like this?

```
<c:if test="1==1">
    <h3>Render this if 1==1</h3>
 </c>
```

Why can't we do the same thing with functions, like this?

```
<fn:...
```

Can we use them inside ${} only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got it right. JSTL functions (fn) can only be used inside ${ } because it affects or results the value of a variable. For example, if I want to know the size of an array named 'array'

```
<c:out value="${fn:length(array)}" />
```

With JSTL tags like `<c:xxx ... />` you process and define variables.
Inside `${ }` you handle the value of a variable

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demonstration.

```
<%@ taglib prefix = "fn" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
          ${fn:toUpperCase("jstl")}  
          ||${fn:substring(fn:toUpperCase(fn:trim("    xxxjstl    ")), 3, 7)}||
    </body>
</html>
```

Output:
JSTL ||JSTL||